# Parameter from url with php and write it into js variable in an if condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url

I am trying to get a parameter from the url with php and write it into a js variable to do some jquery stuff.

my url looks like that

> www.example.com/?v=12345

My Code

```
vnew = "<?php echo $_GET["v"];?>";
if (vnew  == null) {
myfunction();
}
else {
$(".myDiv").attr('src','newsrc');   
$(".title").html("bla");
};
```

if the url is like www.example.com shouldn't the value be 'null', so that my function fires?
However if i set it to '12345' the else condition does not fire either.

What is wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Why would it be null? An empty string is more likely.

Comment: just if vnew = '' ? But why isn't the else condition working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
<?php if ($_GET["v"]) { ?>
    myfunction();
<php } else { ?>
    $(".myDiv").attr('src','newsrc');   
    $(".title").html("bla");
<?php } ?>
```

OR

```
<?php 
if ($_GET["v"]) {
    echo "myfunction();";
} else {
    echo "$(\".myDiv\").attr('src','newsrc'); $(\".title\").html(\"bla\");";
} ?>
```

to check if your condition is working:

```
<?php 
if ($_GET["v"]) {
    echo "myfunction();";
} else {
    echo "Hello";
} ?>
```

Comment: I am taking care of the condition on the server side which is always safer. Instead of closing the php each time, you may echo the text within the php.

Comment: I have included an option where there is only 1 opening and closing php tag

Comment: try this instead - `if (isset($_GET['v']))`

Comment: hm did not change something. i don't get it

Comment: the else condition isn't working.. if v is set. everything is fine. if not nothing happens

Comment: I have changed the code so you can test if the condition is working. Start from there, then move to the jquery.

Comment: I would prefer the solution above but since the title says 'with php' yours is correct

Answer (score 1):

It'll never be null, only an empty string. Think about what the JS output is if no value is passed:

```
vnew = ""; //no PHP output between the quotes, as no value found
```

In any case you don't need PHP to grab the var, in any case.

```
var tmp = location.search.match(/v=([^&]+)/), vnew = tmp ? tmp[1] : null;
```

In this case, the value WILL be `null` if no value is found.

Comment: Ok now the if null query works. But not if v is set.. then nothing happens

Comment: if i set v to '123'. It will return 'v=123,123' now

Comment: Hmm, no. Try alerting `vnew` - if you access the file with `v=12345` in the URL, your alert will be "12345". Tested.

Comment: You are right. But why isn't my else condition working then? :/

Answer (score 0):

Try `var_dump($_GET["v"])` on the base url. Use that value in your comparison.