# How would I call a function in jquery if $_GET was not set?

Tags: php, jquery

Maybe something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
<?php
if (! isset($_GET('/*variable*/')){
  echo '$("#toggle1").click(function(){';}
?>
    $("#n").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#p").hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

Is this possible and if not is there any way that it is possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649327/parameter-from-url-with-php-and-write-it-into-js-variable-in-an-if-condition/21649380

Comment: _Trying_ something out before asking wouldn’t kill you …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible:

```
<?php if (! isset($_GET('/*variable*/')): ?>
  $("#toggle1").click(function(){
    $("#n").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#p").hide();
  });
<?php endif; ?>
});
```

Comment: What doess php endif do and how does the function run if the php script has ended?

Comment: @user3281829 See (PHP: Alternative Syntax)[http://www.php.net/manual/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php] for an explanation of the `endif;`. It is more readable to use `<?php endif; ?>` than `<?php } ?>`. Notice that I used a `:` after the `if` statement instead of a `{` as well.

Comment: @user3281829 PHP runs entirely on your server and sends a response to the web browser. The response could be anything such as (HTML, Javascript, CSS, an image, an mp3 file, a text file). In your case you're returning HTML and an inline Javascript in that HTML. The web browser will run that script it reaches the `<script>` tag. Those four lines will be part of the script if the PHP on your server output them, and they won't be if it didn't.

Comment: If you view source on your page in the two cases, you'll see the difference in your script.